# Why 'another', not 'other'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

A sentence from a newspaper:

> The researchers said another 107 students had problems because of
>   their Internet use.

Shouldn't it be *other* (students) instead of *another* (students)?

Answer (score 1):

You use ***[another](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/another)***  to suggest the idea of more people or things than those already mentioned:

> - ***one more person or thing or an extra amount***:
>
>   - ***For another £30 (= for £30 more)*** you can buy the model with a touchscreen.
>   - Just think, ***in another three months*** (= three months from now) it'll be summer again.

You use ***[other](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/other)*** to refer to someone or something different from the one you are referring to:

> - The product has many other time-saving features.
> - There is no other work available at the moment.
> - The site links to about 24 other sites offering clip art.
> - The man was waiting on the other side of the street.
> - He was economical with the truth - in other words, he was lying.

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

No, this is correct as is. If they were talking about a student (or a few students) in the preceding sentences, from a contextual basis. it would be "another".

In simple words, they are trying to say that apart from the already mentioned students, **another** 107 students had problems.

**Other** does not go with the sentence here.